# Excel: Macro to check folder for new files (based on date in a cell)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro that needs ran once a day. It needs to check a folder (this can be specified within the VBA, as it should not change) and then see if there are any new files.

Currently, this Excel VBA Program prompts the user to select a file. It then does things to the file, and saves the date and shift (from the filename string) into cells on sheet one. The string is always the same, with the only variation being the date and shift number: "My Information MM-DD-YY # Shift"

I want to create code so that the user does not select new files each day, but the program checks for them via a comparison of the cells with the last date and shift ran to the date and shift within the file name in the folder.

Example:

The user ran a file yesterday and it saved the date and shift into cells A1 and B1, 10-04-17 and 2, respectively.

The user forgot to run shift 3 yesterday.

They click the run button today, and the code looks at the directory (specified in the VBA) to see if there are any files where the date is equal to the date in cell A1 (10-04-17) and greater than the shift in cell B1 (2) as well as if there are any files greater than the date in shift A1 (10-04-17) with any shift number. Once it checks, it will select any of the files that meet this criteria and run the macro on them, saving the most recent date and shift to cells A1 and B1.

I already have multifile run functionality written into the existing program.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Comment: You could use the FileDateTime function to get the last saved date and time of files and compare that to whatever date and time the code was last run. This forum is here to help you along with problems youhave with your code, not to write it from scratch for you :-)

Comment: Hi jkpieterse! Thank you for your comment. So with that function, (from what I'm reading online) it appears you have to tell it which file exactly to get the date and time from. Does it have the ability to check a whole folder and "see" the dates and times of each file? (The goal is for as little user interaction as possible.)  And I wasn't expecting anyone to write it for me, I just wanted to be as detailed as possible about what I am trying to write so that everyone could understand and give me the best helpful hints to get started :) Thank you again for your help!

Comment: No you'd have to write code to get the filelist form the foldertree too. Plenty of examples available on-line on how to do that however.

Comment: Okay cool. I will look into that! Thank you again jkpieterse:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who finds this and is curious,

I solved this in a bit of a roundabout way:

1. Create sheet (will stay hidden by turning on and off the visibility)
2. Use filedatetime to view the file I last ran (it's name is saved on the home page (sheet 1) of my workbook)
3. Pulls all the files from a specific folder and prints their filedatetime
4. Sees which filedatetimes are greater than that of the last file I ran
5. For each one found, it gets set as a variable (using a loop) that the macro runs on it
6. Finds the greatest filedatetime and sets this filename to the homepage
7. Deletes all the data from the sheet and hides it